# Is there an easy way to count booleans in Rust?

Tags: rust

I've encountered a scenario in which I have a known, small number of boolean values, but I don't care about them individually, I just want to determine how many of them are true. It seems like there should be a fast way of doing this, but the best I can come up with is the naive solution:

```
let mut count: u8 = 0;
if a {
    count += 1;
}
if b {
    count += 1;
}
if c {
    count += 1;
}
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: do a macro I guess

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could simply do:

```
let count = a as u8 + b as u8 + c as u8;
```

Comment: I find it amazing that the compiler compiles iterator-based solution into [exactly the same assembly](https://godbolt.org/z/3v4zTdEx7).

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to point you to [Michael Anderson's post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69847288/is-there-an-easy-way-to-count-booleans-in-rust/69847395?noredirect=1#comment123467398_69847395), which gives a much nicer syntax than mine.

```rust
let a = true;
let b = false;
let c = true;
let d = true;
let e = false;

let total_true = [a, b, c, d, e].into_iter().filter(|b| *b).count();

println!("{} options are true!", total_true);
```

I've left my original answer below for posterity

**Original Answer**

---

One option is to put your booleans into a Vector, then filter based on if they're true or not.

```rust
    let options = vec![true, false, true, false, false, false, true];
    let total_true = options.into_iter()
                            .filter(|b| *b)
                            .collect::<Vec<bool>>()
                            .len();

    println!("{} options are true!", total_true);
```

We need to convert Vec into an iter, so we can run filter on it.

Then, since filter checks for true boolean expressions, we simply deref our item as `*b` to get the non-borrowed boolean value.

Then we collect that back into a Vector, and get the length to find out how many met our criteria (of being true).

This gives you the total number of true booleans.

Comment: `.collect().len()` can be more efficiently done with [`.count()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.count)

Comment: Also no need for a vec, you can do `[true,false].into_inter().filter(|b| *b).count()`.

Comment: Note however that the last example will break in editions prior to 2021 - you'll have to use either `filter(|b| **b)` or `std::array::IntoIter::new([true,false])`.

Comment: @Cerberus `IntoIterator::into_iter([true, false])` is enough (assuming Rust 1.53 and upwards); the only problem is with `[true, false].into_iter()` (in fact, `std::array::IntoIter::new()` may even be deprecated in the future).